# How to set the browser language of PhantomJS

Tags: testing, browser, phantomjs, headless, dalekjs

I'm using DalekJS with PhantomJS to test a web application. I have important assertions which depend on the browser language. And these fail if the language is not English.

Any Ideas how I can set the default browser language of pantomjs??

Cheers izocan.

Answer (score -1):

Let me answer my own question:

The problem is solved when you use following code in your index.html:

```
  <script>
    localStorage.lang = 'en';
  </script>
```

So the site will be displayed in english no matter which browser is used.

Comment: This solution will only work in your specific case, because your site language is based on the localstorage!