# PhantomJS C# how to change Default language

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Trying to set a Default language in my program. But after much googling i dident find any answers.

How can i input standard english accept language?
is there any document i can read for all functions i can use in c# with PhantomJS? I dident find anything more then playing in Visualstudio controlls.

```
var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();

driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

driverService.LoadImages = false;
driverService.SslProtocol = "tlsv1";
driverService.IgnoreSslErrors = true;
driverService.ProxyType = "http";
driverService.Proxy = "";

using (var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService))
{
    driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080); // Size is a type in assembly "System.Drawing"
    driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();

    driver.Url = "https://www.thewebsite.com";

    Thread.Sleep(5000); // 5sec

    try
    {
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("email")).SendKeys("MyEmail");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("fullName")).SendKeys("MyName");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("username")).SendKeys("MyUsername");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("MyPassword");

        driver.TakeScreenshot().SaveAsFile("LetsSnapascreenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);

    }
    catch (OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException exception)
    {
        var exmsg = exception;
        driver.TakeScreenshot().SaveAsFile("Snaperrorscreenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this if anyone else is looking for it.

```
PhantomJSOptions options = new PhantomJSOptions();

options.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.customHeaders.Accept-Language", "en,en;q=0.5");
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(options);
```

And now it outputs the accept-Language correct

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add a header

```
PhantomJSOptions options = new PhantomJSOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("Accept-Language","en-DE,en;q=0.5"); 
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(options);
```

or write in your index.html as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981929/how-to-set-the-browser-language-of-phantomjs)

```
<script>
   localStorage.lang = 'en';
</script>
```

Comment: options.AddAdditionalCapability("Accept-Language", "en-DE,en;q=0.5");

Does not seems to work. I did try to set useragent with options and it worked. I also ready somewhere about a version bug but i should have the latest PhantomJS installed.

Comment: I cant seems to find "index.html" where should this file be?

Comment: you should change en-DE,en;q=0.5 to the language you  want to set

Comment: Thanks, but i did already solve it i still dont understand where the index.html file is. But i did mange to solve it with my answer below. You where on right track with AddAdditionalCapability. Thanks so much!