# Configure browser language for PhantomJS in Jasmine Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

I am using Jasmine with Karma for unit testing Angular2 application. In the Karma config file I am using PhantomJS as the browser to run the tests.

`browsers: ['PhantomJS']`

I am using ng2-translate module for running translations on my texts with below piece of code:

`userLang = navigator.language.split('-')[0];`

Is it possible to configure PhantomJS to test different browser languages in the test suite?

If yes, then what is the procedure?

Answer (score -1):

This question has already been asked in this topic:

[How to set the browser language of PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981929/how-to-set-the-browser-language-of-phantomjs)

You can check how to do this in this link:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dalekjs/HHt6eoZRQc4

But, basically the only thing that you need to do is to set the customHeaders:

```
 // Set a custom Accept-Language
 var page = require('webpage').create();
 page.customHeaders = {'Accept-Language': 'it-IT'};
```